# $watch not keeping track of model variable

Tags: angularjs

My `$watch` is not updating every change made to the model...

I have in my controller:

```
$scope.JobsLeft = ProductRepository.Model.JobsLeft;
```

In my repository ( a factory ), I change JobsLeft by decrementing the number...

Here is my repository content:

```
var ViewModel = function() 
{
    return {
        Products: [],
        PageCount: [],
        JobsLeft: 0
    };
}();

function JobLoaded()
{
    ViewModel.JobsLeft--;
    alert( ViewModel.JobsLeft );
}

return {
    Model: ViewModel,
    ...
```

JobLoaded() is called within repository functions once they are done.

I have a watch in my controller to keep an eye on the above:

```
$scope.$watch( "JobsLeft" , function(){
    alert( "Doesn't fire when ProductRepository.Model.JobsLeft changes" );
    if( $scope.JobsLeft <= 0 )
    {
        $( ".pagination-loading" ).hide();
    }
}, true );
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I asked something similar a while ago and was told 'Angular is not magic!'. What you need to do is `emit` or `broadcast` a message in the Service when something changes, and pick that up in the controller

Comment: Do I apply the broadcast on the $scope? If so, how do I broadcast from my repository? Am I to assume I need to pass my controller scope into the repo too??

Comment: From memory use $rootscope.$broadcast in the factory and $rootscope.$on in the controller

Comment: Actually you may need to ignite this. Iv though you were using an angular factory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your watching an instance of an integer. If your watch statement was on the actual ViewModel, it would work.

Alternatively, you can make the "JobsLeft" variable an object - something like this:

```
return {
        Products: [],
        PageCount: [],
        JobsLeft: { value: 0 }
    };
```

Then, when you write

```
$scope.JobsLeft = ProductRepository.Model.JobsLeft;
```

The scope's JobsLeft is a reference to the same object inside the ViewModel, and the watch statement should work when written so:

```
$scope.$watch( "JobsLeft.value" , function(){
    alert( "Doesn't fire when ProductRepository.Model.JobsLeft changes" );
    if( $scope.JobsLeft.value <= 0 )
    {
        $( ".pagination-loading" ).hide();
    }
}, true );
```

Don't forget to change the way you edit JobsLeft:

```
function JobLoaded()
{
    ViewModel.JobsLeft.value--;
    alert( ViewModel.JobsLeft.value );
}
```

As a side note, it usually a bad practice to put variables inside the scope itself. It's often best to use the controller for things like this.

Comment: I'd write same answer if you weren't first ;)

Comment: Just to ask about the bad practice thing. I need to have the JobsLeft in my view... that's why I placed it in scope as well.. In this case, is this okay?

Comment: put it in your controller, then in your view, make sure you define your controller in the "myController as someName", then when you bind the variable (for example with ngModel), write ng-model="someName.JobsLeft"